# Copy this folder into the root directory of disksim

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install a simulator (disksim) in ubuntu but i am not getting these two things:
1) Can i just directly copy a folder and paste it into another folder(Disksim) or i have to do it through terminal?
2) What is meant by root directory of Disksim?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can copy and paste just like on any other computer as long as you have the relevant permissions to access that folder. If you get a permission denied error then chances are you'll need to be an admin to access the directory. Personally I find using the terminal easier for this sort of thing because if it is a protected directory I can just re-run the command as admin using sudo and it'll work. But each to their own you can do it in the GUI as well, but I think you'll have to relaunch the file manager as admin using sudo.

By root directory it probably means the top level directory where the software is installed I.e. if you've installed disksim in /etc/disksim then that will be the root directory for disksim and within that there will be sub directories and other files for the use of that program. However it is unusual to hear an install location referred to as the root of a specific app. Normally root refers to the top level of the filesystem (/...).

Comment: "you'll have to relaunch the file manager as admin using sudo". What does this mean?How to do that?

Comment: Start the file manager with sudo in the terminal. I.e. sudo nautilus (that may not be the exact command you'd have to look up what the full package manager name is on Google.

Comment: Have you tried looking up a tutorial for installing disksim if your not sure about how to do it?? There seems to be plenty on Google. https://backendtech.wordpress.com/2015/05/24/running-disksim-4-0-on-64-bit-ubuntu/